# PHP Class Diagram function returns 2 possible data types

Tags: php, function, class, diagram

I'm confused on how to draw a class diagram where a function returns either a boolean value, or an array:

```
private function isSuccessful(&$errors) {
    if (sizeof($errors) > 0) {
        return false; // failed
    } else {
        // $data is an array of key and value pairs
        $data = $this->getData();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Would I write something like this inside of the function section of my class diagram?:

```
- isSuccessful(errors : & array) : boolean | array
```

And also, if any other part of that line looks wrong, I'd love to see what it should look like. Thank you!

Comment: hmm, I guess I could return an empty array instead? Does the rest of this look like something you would find in a class diagram? Not sure if I have done the rest of it correctly.

Comment: I've never done a class diagram, but in doc blocks you do it like `@return bool|string[]` I believe, where you can also show the expected data type for the array contents.